# Substitute R values

Tags: r

Is there a faster way to do the following R substitution

```
for(i in 1:545082) 
{
   index = i*33
   A[index,]$pred = B[index,]$pred
}
```

This loop seems to take forever in R.  Thanks

Comment: What is `A`?  What is `B`?

Comment: Does this do the same thing? `A[1:545083*33,]$pred <- B[1:545082*33,]$pred`

Comment: Thanks GSee, but I like to assign at every 33 items interval.  The set options will work faster using data.table library.

Comment: Then you can use `seq(1, 545082, by=33)`.  That is a different question than how to speed up the code you have.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a `data.frame` you can use data.table's `set` function to replace values by reference.  That should be very fast since there are no copies being made.

```
library(data.table)
set(A, i=1:545082*33, j="pred", B[i:545082*33, "pred"])
```

Answer (score 3):

Some benchmarks. `data.table::set()` is indeed a lot faster than regular data frame assignment, but the gigantic difference comes from vectorized assignment (avoiding the `for` loop).  You can get about a 15000-fold speed increased by using vectorized assignment, or a 200,000-fold increase using `data.table::set()` (again in a vectorized way).

**updated**: added `set` within a `for` loop, which is intermediate in speed (much faster than doing assignment within a loop, and only 50 times slower than doing a vectorized assignment).

```
 n <- 1e5
 m <- 30
 s <- as.integer(seq(1,n,by=m))
 set.seed(101)
 A <- B <- data.frame(x=runif(n),y=runif(n))

 library("data.table")
 library("rbenchmark")
 benchmark(for(i in s) { A[i,]$y <- B[i,]$y },
           for(i in s) { A[i,"y"] <- B[i,"y"] },
           for(i in s) { set (A,i=i,j="y",B[i,"y"]) },
           A[s,"y"] <- B[s,"y"],
           set(A, i=s, j="y", B[s,"y"]),
           replications=20,
        columns = c("test", "elapsed", "relative"))

##                                       test elapsed relative
##                     A[s, "y"] <- B[s, "y"]   0.027     13.5
##       for (...) {  A[i, "y"] <- B[i, "y"]}  94.797  47398.5
##        for (...) {   A[i, ]$y <- B[i, ]$y} 409.383 204691.5
##     for (...) { set(A,i=i,j="y",B[i,"y"])}   1.283    641.5
##          set(A, i = s, j = "y", B[s, "y"])   0.002      1.0
```

Comment: "but the gigantic difference ..." - also because `set` updates by reference. Doing `A[i, j] <- val` on a data.frame copies the column each time in Rv3.1+ or in R v<3.1.0 the entire data.frame (each time).

Comment: so I guess I should really add `for (i in s) { set (A,i=i,j="y",B[i,"y"]) }` to the benchmark ...

Comment: Yes, that'd give an even more clearer picture of the time spent just because of copying columns, and the speed gained due to vectorisation in addition.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
n = 545083*33
A$pred[1:n] = B$pred[1:n]
```

Comment: `1:(545082*33)` is not the same as `1:545083*33`. This answer will give an error about the replacement being a different number of rows than the data.  Try this to see: `BOD$demand[1:10] <- BOD$demand[1:10]`

Comment: Actually, I guess it won't give that error because the OP implies that there are at least `154083*33` rows in both `A` and `B`.  Nonetheless, your code is not doing the same thing as the OP's (or mine in my comment under the Question)